# R: relevel columns of a dataframe based on columns of another dataframe

Tags: r, loops, factors

I have a dataframe called "samples" that looks like so:

```
sample gender disease treatment
sample1      F     d   starved
sample2      F     c       fed
sample3      M     d   starved
sample4      M     d       fed
sample5      M     d   starved
sample6      M     c       fed
etc
```

I need to import this into a script and then relevel() the columns "gender", disease" and "treatment".

**Now importantly, I am building a pipeline which needs to be as general as possible - names of the columns in "samples" may not always be the same, apart from the first column which will always be called "sample".**

Therefore, the aim is for my R script to import a config file (YAML) which would result in a data.frame which would look something like this and would be called "factors":

```
gender disease treatment
     F control       fed
```

Now, how can I loop through this "factors" to tell it to relevel the corresponding column in "samples" - **notice how I made sure the names of the columns match between the 2 dataframes**. I have tried this so far but it doesn't work:

```
for (i in names(factors)){
  samples[[i]] <- relevel(samples[[i]], factors[[i]])
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
 Error in if (ref < 1 || ref > nlev) stop(gettextf("ref = %d must be in 1L:%d",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(ref, 1) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(ref, nlev) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 0):

Note there is a data inconsistency in the example you give: `factors` contains a reference level for `"disease"` that is not present in `samples`: `"control"` vs. `"c"`. I assume this is a typo, and `factors` (and your original YAML file) does in fact have a reference level `"c"` for column `"disease"` (see sample data at the end of the post).

Furthermore I assume that the column class of all columns in `samples` and `factors` is `character`. This should not be a critical requirement, but I haven't tested this for cases where columns in `samples` or `factors` are `factor`s.

Here's an option that should generalise fairly well.

We select all columns from `samples` *except* `samples$sample` (which is always present as per your problem description), and use `purrr::imap` to turn columns into `factors` and `relevel` using the reference level from the corresponding column entry in `factors`. The rest is column-binding with the original `samples$sample` column to give the final re-levelled `samples.relevel` `data.frame`.

```
samples.relevel <- bind_cols(
    samples %>% select(sample),
    samples %>%
        select(-sample) %>%
        imap(~ relevel(factor(.x), factors[[.y]])))
str(samples.relevel)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ sample   : chr  "sample1" "sample2" "sample3" "sample4" ...
# $ gender   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 2 2 2 2
# $ disease  : Factor w/ 2 levels "c","d": 2 1 2 2 2 1
# $ treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "fed","starved": 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

---

### Sample data

```
samples <- read.table(text =
    "sample gender disease treatment
sample1      F     d   starved
sample2      F     c       fed
sample3      M     d   starved
sample4      M     d       fed
sample5      M     d   starved
sample6      M     c       fed", header  = T, colClasses = "character")


factors <- read.table(text =
    "gender disease treatment
     F c       fed", header = T, colClasses = "character")
```